# Getting a single child element with a given name with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Let's say I have XML which looks like this:

```
<paper>
    <header>
    </header>
    <body>
        <paragraph>
        </paragraph>
    </body>
    <conclusion>
    </conclusion>
</paper>
```

Is there a way I can just get `conclusion`, without making an ugly loop like:

```
for child in paper.children do
    if child.name == "conclusion"
        conclusion = child
    end
end

puts conclusion
```

Ideally something like python's `Element.find('conclusion')`.

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html)? I found it by googling for "nokogiri find element by name"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `xpath` method.

```
node = doc.xpath("//conclusion")[0]
```

or, if you know is just one

```
node = doc.at_xpath("//conclusion")
```

Comment: Thanks, `.at_xpath` was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: FWIW, you can also use CSS-style selectors (e.g. `doc.css('conclusion')` or `doc.at_css('conclusion')`.

Comment: Thanks @orde, very nice